# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort' in comparing 2 lists in python

Tags: python

I am new in programming, I try to train from the codewars.com..
the exercise is to compare 2 lists and to find "same" elements..
"Same" means, here, that the elements in b are the elements in a squared, regardless of the order.
This is my code, it passes all the tests but I have an error:

```
This is my code:
    def comp(a1, a2):
        new_list = []
    
        for a in a1:
            b = a * a
            new_list.append(b)
    
        print(new_list)
        print(a2)
    
        a2_sorted = a2.sort()
        new_list.sort()
    
        if new_list == a2_sorted:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    
    print(comp(a1=[121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11],
               a2=[11 * 11, 121 * 121, 144 * 144, 19 * 19, 161 * 161, 19 * 19, 144 * 144, 19 * 19]
               ))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'****
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that your code as shown just returns ``False``, it does not raise any error.

Comment: `list.sort()` returns `None`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort